# CSS Variables for ExtJS combobox

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have to create a custom stylesheet for my ExtJS application. I have created it using sencha command and by modifying Package/MyCustomTheme/sass/etc/all.scss file. It has changed the base colors etc of the application and panels. When I am including a combobox on my page, it does not seem to have any style applied to it. What variables I need to include in the .scss file for combobox? What is the correct way to change the style of all the components used in the application?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom theme, built with `secha app build`, and then you add a new component that needs extra css rules, you have to rebuild your app before the css for that component gets included in the css of your custom theme.

I'm not sure if I'm clear:

1. Build your app with custom theme with `sencha app build`
2. Include a new component class (`Ext.form.field.ComboBox` in your case).
3. Now the css file of your custom theme will miss the combobox css rules.
4. Rebuild your app with `sencha app build`
5. Your css theme files are now complete and everything's OK.